# Asymmetrik/node-fhir-server-mongo, how to enable post operation

Tags: node-fhir-server-core, hl7-fhir

I have set up Asymetric fhir server mongo implementation described here https://github.com/Asymmetrik/node-fhir-server-mongo, by default it supports GET and PUT operations. Just wondering how to enable POST operations.

Answer (score 0):

Doing POST depends on the operation and route, see this route config for which operations support post, https://github.com/Asymmetrik/node-fhir-server-core/blob/master/src/server/route.config.js. In short, operation post, create, and search all support the POST method.